# Cakephp 2 plugin routes not working in form actions

Tags: php, cakephp

I am making my own cakephp 2 plugin called Rma and for this plugin I made some routes. When I want to make a form linking to the edit page, the link is different from the link in my routes file. In the browser are my routes working, but cakephp generate different links when I change form actions or echo the Html Link.

The code `echo $this->Html->url(array('plugin' => 'Rma', 'controller' => 'RmaRequests', 'action' => 'edit', 2));` gives me the following url: '/Rma/RmaRequests/edit/2' while the url in the routes file is 
'/rma/edit/:id'. Cakephp gives me the wrong url.

This is my routes.php in the plugin config folder (app/Plugin/Rma/Config/routes.php):

```
Router::connect('/rma/new', [
    'plugin' => 'Rma',
    'controller' => 'RmaRequests',
    'action' => 'add'
]);
Router::connect('/rma/edit/:id', [
    'plugin' => 'Rma',
    'controller' => 'RmaRequests',
    'action' => 'edit'
],
    array(
        // order matters since this will simply map ":id" to
        // $articleId in your action
        'pass' => array('id'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    ));

Router::connect('/rma/new/:id/', array(
    'plugin' => 'Rma', 'controller' => 'RmaRequestProducts', 'action' => 'add'),
    array(
        // order matters since this will simply map ":id" to
        'pass' => array('id'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

I've also tried to place the route in my application routes.php, but that still doesn't solve the problem.

This is the way how I load my plugin in app/Config/bootstrap.php:
`CakePlugin::load('Rma', array('routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true));`

Is there something I forgot or something that I did wrong? I am using CakePHP version 2.5.1

Comment: You probably have other routes connected earlier that are matching that URL array, probably some catch-all routes like `/:controller/:action/*`.

Comment: I found one route like that. I removed that route but the url is still the same. I've also changed the route from /rma/... to /rmaplugin/.... but it still doesn't work

Comment: If the URL is still the same, then there's very likely still a route that catches it. You'll have to check all your routes (search the whole codebase for `Router::connect`), and show them all if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Here can you find my complete routes.php file (app/Config/routes.php): https://pastebin.com/Pb7VK5kt. The theme has no routes by the way

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used CakePHP 2 in a long time, and totally forgot how it handles named parameters and non-matching routes, it requires you to use the name in the URL array, and it will not throw an error for non matching routes, but generate a fallback URL :( Long story short, problem is probably that you should use `'id' => 2` in your URL array, not just `2`.

Comment: You are my hero. This solved my problem. Thank you so much @ndm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, thnx to @ndm in the comments:

The Url has an named parameter called id. Instead of:
 `echo $this->Html->url(array('plugin' => 'Rma', 'controller' => 'RmaRequests', 'action' => 'edit', 2));`

It must be

`echo $this->Html->url(array('plugin' => 'Rma', 'controller' => 'RmaRequests', 'action' => 'edit', 'id'=> 2));`